# Save raw response/binary data for a PDF response

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, amazon-s3

I am getting back a response in node to fetch a PDF that I would like to save the binary data and upload it to S3 which I can then pull as I please for historical purposes.   Right now I am having problems trying to extract that PDF raw data/binary data so that I can save that as a PDF and upload it, I think I am getting closer.   this is the response.body that I am getting.

```
PassThrough {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: null,
    pipesCount: 0,
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: false,
    destroyed: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
  },
  readable: true,
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
    unpipe: [Function: onunpipe],
    error: [ [Function: onerror], [Function] ],
    close: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: onclose] },
    finish: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: onfinish] }
  },
  _eventsCount: 5,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _writableState: WritableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    finalCalled: false,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: false,
    ended: false,
    finished: false,
    destroyed: false,
    decodeStrings: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    corked: 0,
    sync: true,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    afterWriteTickInfo: null,
    bufferedRequest: null,
    lastBufferedRequest: null,
    pendingcb: 0,
    prefinished: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: false,
    bufferedRequestCount: 0,
    corkedRequestsFree: {
      next: null,
      entry: null,
      finish: [Function: bound onCorkedFinish]
    }
  },
  writable: true,
  allowHalfOpen: true,
  _transformState: {
    afterTransform: [Function: bound afterTransform],
    needTransform: false,
    transforming: false,
    writecb: null,
    writechunk: null,
    writeencoding: null
  },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

This is my code:

```
platform.on(platform.events.loginSuccess, async function(e) {
    let resp = await platform.get('/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/'+accountId+'/message-store', {
        messageType: ['Fax'],
        dateFrom: ['2021-05-01'],
        dateTo: ['2021-05-16']


    })
    let jsonObj = await resp.json()
    let attachId = jsonObj.records[0].id

    let getMessageContent = await platform.get('/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/'+accountId+'/message-store/'+attachId+'/content/'+attachId, {
        contentDisposition: ['Inline']
    })
```

I know the response I am getting is correct because if I run that URL in postman and use the preview option, I can see the pdf (see screenshot).  What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks about right to me. The response.body is a readable [node.js stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) containing the binary data, and my guess is that Postman reads this stream automatically and displays the result.

The good news is that this type of stream is exactly what S3 wants as a request body when uploading files, which means that you do not need to save it anywhere - you can just pass it through directly to S3. Depending on your implementation, your code could look something like this:

```js
    const result = await s3Client.upload({
        Bucket: 'MY_S3_BUCKET',
        Key: 'myfilename.pdf',
        Body: response.body,
    }).promise();
```

Where response.body is the stream you have logged above. This should put the pdf file right up in S3 ready for downloading.

But if you do insist on saving the file, you can also pass the stream to the [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) method like so:

```js
fs.writeFileSync('my-pdf.pdf', response.body);
```